# PHP numerical preg_match

Tags: php, scripting, preg-match

Currently I have a snippet of code that looks that looks like this:

```
preg_match('/^(\D+)\s=\s(\d+)\s=\s(\D+)\s=\s(\d+)/', trim($row), $matches);
```

What I want to do is allow it to use numbers too, because in my output it shows no numbers. How do I do this? Please help!

Comment: What is the input string and the expected output?

Comment: @Gokhan137 Please write what `$row` contains, a few lines or use pastebin.com to show bigger strings. And example what should be in output `$matches`.

Comment: @S17514 the answer solve your problem? plz let us know...

Answer (score 0):

Check if this solve your problem:

```
preg_match('/^(.+)\s=\s(\d+)\s=\s(\D+)\s=\s(\d+)/', trim($row), $matches);
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10963620/1439823

If is your whish allow numbers and anything between equal "=" you shall use the code below

```
preg_match('/^(.+)\s=\s(.+)\s=\s(.+)\s=\s(.+),/', trim($row), $matches);
```